# Understanding the Dependencies of a Makefile (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, dependencies, conceptual

While working on a C++ project, I noticed that I was making changes to one of the header files  linked in my main code, but the make utility was not registering it. I had to force it to compile differently given the changes using "make - B".

I want to know why this is the case; is it because of how my makefile is written, how my files depend on each other, both, or neither?

Here is my makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wvla -g
//CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11

all:    main.o game.o zombie.o
        g++ $(FLAGS)  game.o main.o zombie.o -o main $(CXXFLAGS)

game:   game.cpp 
        g++ $(FLAGS) -c game.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

zombie: zombie.cpp
        g++ $(FLAGS) -c zombie.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

main:   main.cpp
        g++ $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp pairing_heap.h $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I made a change to  pairing_heap.h 
 which is #included in my main file.

Why did make not notice that it should compile again? Because I feel like this is a conceptual misunderstanding, I felt that it was not necessary to include the changes I made or the output difference when I did "make - B". They were simple things like cout's and cerr's included in the new pairing_heap.h that were not being picked up until forced.

Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make doesn't really know anything about any particular programming language or tool, so it doesn't understand that C/C++ files depend on headers as well as source files.  It just has rules of the form

```
target: dependencies
        actions
```

All it knows from this is that the file `target` depends on the files listed in `dependencies`, and if any of those files are newer, the commands in `actions` should be run to update `target`.  That's really it -- everything that make does comes from this simple idea of target files, dependencies, and actions.

Now there *is* more to it -- make has a bunch of built-in rules for common things you often want to do, as well as ways to specify 'pattern' rules -- rules where the target contains a wildcard, so can be used for many different targets that depend on other files with related names.

Now in your case, you have the rule:

```
all:    main.o game.o zombie.o
        g++ $(FLAGS)  game.o main.o zombie.o -o main $(CXXFLAGS)
```

which says to remake the file `all`, if its older than the files `main.o`, `game.o` or `zombie.o` it should run the command.  That's the first rule in the file, so it is what gets built by default when you type `make`.

Now, you probably don't have a file called `all` (if you did `make` probably wouldn't do anything), but that's generally fine, as if it doesn't exist, its obviously not up to date, so the command needs to run.
When a command needs to run, it also checks any of the dependencies to see if they in turn have dependencies that are older (so need to be rebuilt).  Since these files all end in `.o`, they match a built-in rule that knows how to build them from a file with the same name, except ending with `.cpp`, so its runs those actions if (and only if) the `.cpp` file is newer.

Now, you say, "what about my other rules -- what do they do?"  Well it turns out they don't do anything.  They are rules to build files named `game`, `zombie`, and `main`, and since you never ask to build those files and nothing else depends on them, they do nothing.  You might as well delete them.

You also ask "How do I make it rebuild if the header file changes?"  Well, if you add a rule with no actions (just target and dependencies) it will just add those dependencies to another rule (built-in in this case) that *does* have an action.  So if you add a line like:

```
main.o: pairing_heap.h
```

(with no action), `make` will add this dependency to the built-in rule that know how to build `main.o` from `main.cpp` and will run that rule (recompiling `main.cpp`) if *either* `main.cpp` or `pairing_hep.h` is newer than `main.o` -- which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the big picture, then diving into the finer details. Very pedagogical; I can dig it. I foresee a much better relationship between me and makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

You are listing `pairing_heap.h` in the recipe for `main`, which does not make it a dependency of `main` (besides, you should never pass headers to the compiler like this), for that you need to write the rule as follows:

```
main:   main.cpp pairing_heap.h 
        g++ $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)
```

There are a number of other things that are incorrect in your file, such as the fact that your targets are not actual files (`main:` should be `main.o:` etc.), and you aren't making use of automatic variables or pattern rules, but it's probably easier to just replace everything with the following

```
CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wvla -g
SOURCES  := $(wildcard *.cpp)

main: $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

-include $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)
```

which leverages make's [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) and gcc's/clang's auto dependency generation to make an executable called `main`.